# Google line chart legend display name

Tags: javascript, vb.net, charts, google-visualization, legend

how can I 'change' the display name in google chart legend using variable (so every time when user select the string from drop down list, the 'dynamic' string will display in legend)? or any other way i can put the information on legend area?

Screenshot1, i want to display variable 'string' in legend
[image]

Screenshot2, code behind in VB, cannot dim the variable in data add object statement.
or is there any other way can show in the legend?
[image]

Screenshot3, i tried code in script, but it didn't retrieve the variable.
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: you should be able to use a variable as the column label. but it's not clear, are you building javascript dynamically using vb? what happened with Screenshot3, did you receive an error in the console?

Comment: i think so, i can retrieve variable when i click the button on asp, the variable pass to sql stored procedure in vb (https://www.dropbox.com/s/tet60lii39367fa/Capture4.JPG?dl=0) and (https://www.dropbox.com/s/sut601ea7d7wod5/Capture6.JPG?dl=0).  There is no error, but duplicated "name" in legend.(https://www.dropbox.com/s/cwuu3pntynxw4v4/Capture5.JPG?dl=0)

Comment: thanks -- and note: it would be more helpful to paste the actual code, rather than a picture of the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the column labels are initially set when using `arrayToDataTable` to create the data table

so, instead of using `addColumn`, you just need to change the existing labels

replace...

```
data.addColumn("number", '" + SelectedLine1 + "');
...
```

with...

```
data.setColumnLabel(1, SelectedLine1);
data.setColumnLabel(2, SelectedLine2);
data.setColumnLabel(3, SelectedLine3);
```